# Sharing Printer/Scanner in a domain

Tags: domain, printer

I have a setup like this:

10 computers are a member of workgroup.  We only have 1 scanner, so everytime that userA has to scan, he will just go to UserB (user B has an access to the scanner).

UserB will just paste the scanned document to the desktop of USER A, because they are in Workgroup, USER B can view every folder, docs and even desktop of all user which a member of workgroup.

Now, we want to switch in Active Directory, and all users must be joined to Domain.

What would be the good setup for scanner, so UserB can also put the scanned document to UserA desktop.

I am thinking that I might give UserB an ADministrator Rights so he can view every desktop of all users joined to domain. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend giving them admin privileges unless they really need it, as that would violate the security principal of least privilege.

I would recommend setting up a print server with the scanner attached to it, and the Print and Document services role (in Server 2008R2.) with the Distributed Scanner service enabled.

Comment: thanks for the answer @Davidw . however, im running server 2003

Comment: You might try this: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/31591-42-share-5590-scanner-windows-2003-server